# Hash based table returning null

Tags: java, guava

I have a function that is returning null.

Example input:
`String alice=table.get("Alice","Smith");`

Here's my code:

```
public void setTab() {
    table.put("Alice","Smith","Manager");
    ...
}

// get all persons with a surname of Smith
final Collection<String> smiths = table.column("Smith").values();

// get all persons with a firstName of Bob
final Collection<String> bobs = table.row("Bob").values();

// get a specific person
    final String alice=table.get("Alice", "Smith");

public void printSpecial() {
    System.out.println(alice);
    System.out.println(smiths);
    System.out.println(bobs);

}

public void prinTab()  {
    for (Cell<String, String,String> cell: table.cellSet()){
        System.out.println(cell.getRowKey()+" "+cell.getColumnKey()+" "+cell.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, it's null because (unless you haven't copied the code correctly), the line

```
final String alice=table.get("Alice", "Smith");
```

Is called when the class is instantiated.  However, your `setTab()` function presumably isn't called until sometime after that.  You can fix this by not setting `alice` until after you have called `setTab()`